# Searching for TCP servers

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, serversocket

I'm using the the examples provided by Microsoft to learn how to use TCP servers in C#. For TCPListener I use this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.aspx , and for TCPCLient I use this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.aspx (the examples are at the bottom of the page).

Until now I've managed to connect and send messages to other PCs connected to the same router. The problem is that I also have to manually introduce the IP of the computer I want to connect. Isn't there any way to see what TCP servers are available/online in my LAN network ?

Comment: Are you looking for IP multicasting??

Comment: I'm not very familiar with the IP multicast, but what I am looking for is rather (for the beginning at least) a simple chat application that can send messages and even files between PCs.

Comment: Check this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12893/TCP-IP-Chat-Application-Using-C and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa478452.aspx !!!!

Comment: @RahulTripathi, sorry, but your answer doesn't answer my question. I still have to introduce the ip of a computer so i can make a connection. Is there no other way to do that ?